# Data is not being inserted in MySQL database

Tags: java, html, mysql, servlets

I have been trying to develop an webpage using Java.

This my `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simple Dark Form</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
<form action="../PatientRegistrationServlet" method="post">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sofia' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class='login'>
  <h2>Register</h2>
  <input name='First Name' placeholder='First Name' type='text'>
  <input name='Last Name' placeholder='Last Name' type='text'>
    <input name='ad1' placeholder='Address Line 1' type='text'>
      <input name='Birthdate' placeholder='Birt date' type='text'>
        <input name='ad2' placeholder='Address Line 2' type='text'>
        <input name='Country' placeholder='Country' type='text'>
  <input name='State' placeholder='State' type='text'>
  <input name='city' placeholder='city' type='text'>
    <input name='pcode' placeholder='Pincode' type='text'>
    <input name='Blood group' placeholder='Blood group' type='text'>
     <input name='Email' placeholder='E-Mail' type='text'>
  <input name='Gender' placeholder='Gender' type='text'  >  
        <input name='mobilno' placeholder='Mobile no' type='text'>
        <input id='pw' name='pw' placeholder='Password' type='password'>

<div class='agree'>
    <input id='agree' name='agree' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='agree'></label>Accept rules and conditions
  </div>
  <input class='animated' type='submit' value='Register' ">
  <a class='forgot' href="../cpaneliclinix/login.jsp">Already have an account?</a>
</div>
    </form>
          </body>
</html>
```

This is my java servlet page code:

```java
package com.iclinix.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/PatientRegistrationServlet")
public class PatientRegistrationServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public PatientRegistrationServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String fname = request.getParameter("First Name");
        String lname = request.getParameter("Last Name");
        String addr1 = request.getParameter("ad1");
        String bd = request.getParameter("Birthdate");
        String addr2 = request.getParameter("ad2");
        String cntry = request.getParameter("Country");
        String st1 = request.getParameter("State");
        String ct = request.getParameter("city");
        String pc = request.getParameter("pcode");
        String bg = request.getParameter("Blood group");
        String  mail= request.getParameter("Email");
        String gen = request.getParameter("Gender");
        String mno = request.getParameter("mobilno");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pw");       

            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/iclinix","root","root");
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO tbl_patient_registration (first_name, last_name, add1, birth_date, add2, country, state, city, pincode, bloodgroup, email, gender, mobileno, password)"+ "values('"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+addr1+"','"+bd+"','"+addr2+"','"+cntry+"','"+st1+"','"+ct+"','"+pc+"','"+bg+"','"+mail+"','"+gen+"','"+mno+"','"+pass+"')");


            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

I have been trying to store details of registration page which is given by user in form in MySQL database.
MySQL database is connected with it.

[Here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDHtl.png)

image link
Everthing works fine when I try to go with only 3 fields that are first name, last name and password, but when I try to add more fields and run it, nothing gets updated in the database.
There is no error in servlet.

It works with only first name and last name. Please can anyone help me?

Comment: I assume that there are no exceptions being thrown, so do you need a transaction with a commit?

Comment: i dont know basically what does it mean,,as i am new to this field....

Comment: see this page https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Comment: ok..But how does it gonna help me..when i use on this fields : First name,Last name,password.its works fine..but as i try to use more fileds like address 1,2,country etc...it just run but no data is being updated in mysql workbench

Comment: Side note: **Never ever** use string concatenation to create SQL statements. Learn to use [PreparesStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)s.

Comment: Eclipse for coding,Mysql workbench for database

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following:

```
String insertStatement = "INSERT INTO tbl_patient_registration (first_name, last_name, add1, birth_date, add2, country, state, city, pincode, bloodgroup, email, gender, mobileno, password) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(insertStatement);
pst.setString(1, fname);
pst.setString(2, lname);
pst.setString(3, addr1);
pst.setDate(4, bd); // here I am guessing that the type of the column is date; if I am wrong use setString instead

... // set the rest of the parameters here

pst.setString(14, pass);

pst.executeUpdate(); // execute the statement after setting the params
```

This is better than string concatenation because it handles

- SQL injection and,
- is readable (my taste) and is less error prone.

If you want more information about the `PreparedStatement` look at the [JDBC tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: it doesnt work.no..is the whole servelts is wrong or there is something problem with other shits.

Comment: n also my database is also working as i have been using it on another login servlets.

Comment: You can check a couple of things: 1. why the dots (`..`) in `action="../PatientRegistrationServlet"`? 2. debug your servlet code or just use `System.out.println()` all the params 3. Look into your log file or console if there are exceptions. 4. white spaces are allowed in HTML input control names (like `First Name`) but I would remove them; use instead names like `firstName`. If it still doesn't work leave me a comment and I'll try it myself today in the evening.

Comment: tx..it works..i change my index.html and start with an fresh servlet and everything works fine..tx stack group